# Can I create a html element if I have x and y coordinates of mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to highlight a section of text in html document .For highlight i am getting text start x,y with respect to certain reference element and width and height .I want to insert a span there and then toggle css style to do highlight and unhighlight

Comment: Yes.  Would you care to be more specific as to your scenario and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes you can. Use CSS to position the element.

Comment: @DoctorMick i am trying to hihlight a section of text for .For highlight i am getting text start x,y and width and height .I want to insert a span there and then toggle css style to do hilight and unhilight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b76rw/

```
var mousex = 0, mousey = 0;

$('div').mousemove(function(e) {
   mousex = e.clientX;
   mousey = e.clientY;
}).click(function() {
    var newel = "<span style=\"position:absolute; top:"+mousey+"px;left:"+mousex+"px\">newElement</span>";

   $(this).append(newel);
});
```

Comment: Thanks .Can i specify where to put </span> based on width in pixel .Basically i want to highlight and un highlight a section of text for which i am getting the enlosing rectangle from backend .

Comment: what width do you want? it can be any element with any style.

Comment: say i have x ,y and width .x and y specify start of text selection and width (in pixels ) specifies where selection end . i want to insert a span element there

Comment: honestly i have no idea what you mean @rajesh sorry.. If you want to offset the element by width, you can add margin-left: 50px; or whatever.. or add a value to mousex/mousey etc.. if you want to add width to the span you should probally use a div and give it a width in its style attribute, same way as top and left in answer.